# How-to configure kaa-node heap size

Tags: kaa

I am trying to run a kaa server on a raspberry pi, and have successfully compiled it from source on the ARM processor, and installed the resulting .deb package.

However when i try to start the kaa-node i get the following error.

Starting Kaa Node...

Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4G

The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I have tried to search through the /etc/kaa-node/conf directory, and the bin files, but I can't see where the "4G" setting is actually set, so that I might change it to something smaller and launch this on the Pi which has 1G of RAM.

Can someone point me to the correct place to make this modification, while still making use of launching the server as a service using the built in utilities? I know i could just run it with java, and passit my own JAVA_OPTIONS.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to find the "kaa-node" file in /etc/default/ and modify the JAVA_OPTIONS in it.
We try to modify it to config heap size and GC for our Kaa server.

Answer (score 1):

You can try starting kaa-node service with

```
service kaa-node start -Xmx500M
```

To limit heap size by 500mb.
If it won't work, try

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx500m
```

To set global JVM heap size limit.